# AWS Aurora MySql2 connection from One Lambda function to another in AWS Step Functions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, function, lambda, step

I have a AWS Aurora database and I'm using mysql2 in node.js to connect to it using rds proxy. I have created a lambda function which does this connection. I'm using AWS Step Function, is there any way we can send this connection to the next lambda that gets called in the step function and run sql queries there. Or is this not the way we should do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not pass the database connection to an upcoming step. I would open the connection and query data from the same Lambda function (same step). If you need data in an upcoming step, pass the result set in JSON.